# gsutil - regex with alternative not working

Tags: python, regex, gsutil

I am looking to synchronize content between Google bucket and my local directory. I want to ignore certain files while performing this operation.

Like I want to ignore file which ends with country.csv and version.csv at the end.

So I use following regex, which doesn't work

```
    gsutil -m rsync -x ".*country\.csv$|.*version\.csv$" gs://[bucket_id] test/
```

I have tested this regex on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/)

On the other hand when I try with single regex, it works

```
    gsutil -m rsync -x ".*country\.csv$" gs://[bucket_id] test/
```

I am working on windows machine.
And I am referring [gsutil documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync#synopsis)

Can any one identify where the problem is ?

**Edit :**

Error on gsutil "not recognized as internal or external command, operable program or batch file"

Comment: The documentation suggests using single quotes around regex. Have you tried it?

Comment: @SilentMonk: single quotes don't work on windows, Above mentioned single regex also works with double quotes only

Comment: What about the double backslashes? On Unix, the single quotes prevent expansion, i.e. `\\` gets passed natively to python, which causes a native backlash to appear in the python string, which is what you want.

Comment: @SilentMonk: double backslashes also don't work on windows. I have to use single backslash to escape dot(.)

Comment: Try the same thing using `powershell` rather than `cmd`. Then at least you should be able to use single quotes, if that matters. The `|` shouldn't be treated as a shell pipe, at least.

Comment: @Chris Lear: I am using `Google cloud SDK shell`, not `cmd`. gsutil is part of this SDK. So I guess `powershell` will not help.

Comment: The Google cloud SDK shell is just `cmd` started with a batch file that setts the `PATH` variable and executes a `cd` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This ought to work:

```
gsutil -m rsync -x ".*country\.csv$^|.*version\.csv$" gs://[bucket_id] test/
```

See eg [How to pass a quoted pipe character to cmd.exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200235/how-to-pass-a-quoted-pipe-character-to-cmd-exe)